# In R is there a way to display hierarchical clustering in a venn diagram

Tags: r, nvd3.js

I am trying to display a hierarchical cluster as a **venn diagram** or any other useful display **BESIDES** a dendrogram. I want to be able to display my data in many different view types.

Currently doing this will plot a dendrogram:

```
x <- hclust(dist(mtcars))
plot(x)
```

What can I do to display a cluster diagram that **LOOKS** like this:

https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/images/3/3b/Lecture23VennClusters_OldKiwi.jpg

or this

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535

or anything else that makes sense for displaying cluster data in this example.

Preferably I want to be able to do this in **Shiny**, but a simple R example will suffice.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this site  http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/venn.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plots you showed are cluster plots.  There are different ways to make these plots.  Here's one approach.  You can vary the symbols, or turn them off, and likewise for fill, as desired.  Also, there are options for dendrogram plotting, ie [here](http://rpubs.com/gaston/dendrograms)

```
library(cluster)

head(mtcars)
fit <- kmeans(mtcars, 3)  # 3 clusters
aggregate(mtcars, by=list(fit$cluster), mean)
newmtcars <- data.frame(mtcars, fit$cluster)
head(newmtcars)

# plot cluster solution
library(cluster)
clusplot(mtcars, fit$cluster, 
         color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, lines=0)
```

[image]

refs: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html
      https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31083/how-to-produce-a-pretty-plot-of-the-results-of-k-means-cluster-analysis

I'm not sure how a Venn diagram would differ from the above plot.  Maybe there needs to overlapping groups.  That depends on the data and the tree command.  Could try varying the tree command, in this case kmeans, shows a small overlap when the number of iterations is selected.

```
fit <- kmeans(mtcars, 3, iter.max = 2)  # 3 clusters, low number of iterations
clusplot(mtcars, fit$cluster, 
         color=TRUE, shade=FALSE, lines=0)
```

[image]

One approach to do this with hierarchical clustering is to extract the groups from the tree, and then use clusplot on the resulting groups.

```
fit <- hclust(dist(mtcars))
groups <- cutree(fit, k=3)
clusplot(mtcars, groups[rownames(mtcars)], 
         color=TRUE, shade=FALSE, lines=0)
```

To see how the data segments with more cuts in a tree, including hierarchial tree, one approach is to use cut followed by clusplot

```
heir_tree_fit <- hclust(dist(mtcars))
for (ncut in seq(1,10)) {
  group <- cutree(heir_tree_fit, k=ncut)
  clusplot(mtcars, group[rownames(mtcars)], 
           color=TRUE, shade=FALSE, lines=0, main=paste(ncut,"cuts"))
}
```

Here are the figures for 2, 6, and 10 cuts

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can make one plot with all the cuts

```
par(new=FALSE)
for (ncut in seq(1,10)) {
  group <- cutree(heir_tree_fit, k=ncut)
  clusplot(mtcars, group[rownames(mtcars)], 
           color=TRUE, shade=FALSE, lines=0, xlim=c(-5,5),ylim=c(-5,5))
  par(new=TRUE)
}
par(new=FALSE)
```

[image]
Another approach to making a Venn diagram of hierarchical clustering is to extract the groups from the tree, and then use vennDiagram on the resulting groups.

```
# To make a Venn diagram
# source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("limma")
library(limma)
inGrp1 <- groups==1
inGrp2 <- groups==2
inGrp3 <- groups==3
vennData <- cbind(inGrp1, inGrp2, inGrp3)

aVenn <- vennCounts(vennData)
vennDiagram(aVenn)
```

[image: VennDiagramMTCAR]

Comment: That's pretty cool, but OP was looking for a way to visualize hierarchical clusters using a Venn-diagram-like plot.

Comment: @jarfa Added an approach to visualize hierarchical clusters using a Venn diagram.

Comment: What OP is trying to recreate (and what I'd love to see as well) is something like https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/images/3/3b/Lecture23VennClusters_OldKiwi.jpg . A venn diagram for k-means isn't interesting. What's interesting is a diagram that shows how a given point has a hierarchical set of classes. Like a dendrogram with a spatial component.

Comment: @jarfa just use cut tree followed by clusplot, see above

Comment: Wow thanks alot this is very helpfull.  Now I just need to turn this into Shiny. I will post what I get when I do. Meanwhile, giving user/ credit for a fantastic answer.